# How to use NativeScript plugins?

Tags: plugins, nativescript

Silly question: following the picture, are these disable icons mean that the plugin is unusable with Angular and VueJS ?

[image: NS Plugin]

Answer (score 0):

Any plugin that's not dependent on a particular framework, in other words developed for NativeScript Core can be integrated with any framework.

[nativescript-sim-info](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-sim-info) can be used with any framework, the icons there just lets you know the plugin do not have explicit support for frameworks like Angular / Vue etc., But you wouldn't need it for a non-UI plugin. Only plugins that helps with UI may need explicit support.